# Reading files in android every 512bytes

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-file

I have one file around 5KB and need to read the file like 512 Bytes with respect to some time periods until the file ends.

How can I do this?

Anyone please help me. What is my intention is separate the file into 512bytes of data and send through the Bluetooth using asynchronousTask.

Comment: Am new to android developing,now i did somthing like read the file and send totally via bluetooth.

Comment: What is the issue now?